# How to scrape hyperlink from function inside javascript tag, no elements used in <script> tag. Just a single function inside <script>

Tags: javascript, python, function, selenium

Bear with me, I am very new to python and scaping but eager to learn.

I am trying to read a hyperlink which is nested inside a function within  tags using python.

So far I learned, I can not use BeautifulSoup because the script has to be loaded by a webdriver first.
I installed selenium (although heavy on the job) & chrome webdriver, and open the link in either headless or full browser.
Some of the suggestions about scraping JS are i scrape with Regex and/or find_element_by_id().
There are however no id tags in the script.
Only thing I can find in the source between the  tags is a $(document).ready(function() which opens up Jplayer and refers to a hyperlink. My goal is to copy/scrape the hyperlink.

Any ideas how i can scrape from the 'string' of the function so i can select only the part with the hyperlink and store is as variable?

Comment: It would be useful if you could give a link to what page you are trying to scrape.

Comment: Thank you, the link to the page is is https://soundgasm.net/u/rocketear/One-Art-by-Elizabeth-Bishop, as you can see in the source the file link is inside the third <script> tag, i find difficulty scraping whatever is part of the JS code inside the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not fully sure what you are trying to accomplish, but this is what I have understood. You want to get the link of some webpage element.

Selenium has multiple functions to find the element of your choice, for example:

- `find_element_by_class_name`
- `find_element_by_id`
- `find_element_by_xpath` (usually most accurate in my experience)
- `find_element_by_tag_name`
- `find_element_by_link_text`
- ...

If you want to find multiple elements you could use `find_elements_by_` which would return a list.

You can define a element by one of these and then get the `href` attribute of it. For example:

```py
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_to_your_element")
print(element.get_attribute("href"))  # None if element doesn't have a href attribute
```

EDIT: Finding xpath of elements on webpage.

I usually use the extension called [ruto](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ruto-xpath-finder/ilcoelkkcokgeeijnopjnolmmighnppp?hl=en)

This is how you use it:

1. Right-click on an element you want to find the xpath of
2. Hover over "Ruto - XPath Finder"
3. Select "Standard"
4. Click on your extension icon

4.5. You may have to click on the icon fairly quick, since usually it resets it in about 3 seconds. After you click on the extension it will hold the results till you click away.

5. Copy a xpath

[image: ruto image]

NOTE: This is not sponsered by ruto in any way.

EDIT2: Get link from page source

I have finally understood your problem, and came up with a solution.

First you have to get the page source of the website:

```py
import requests

response = requests.get(link_to_website)
content = response.content.decode("utf-8")
print(content)  # this will print the page source of your webpage
```

Now we need to find the link. I think the easiest way to do that is by using regular expressions. We can start with a quotation, and then go all the way up to .m4a, ending off with a quotation.

This is the regex I came up with: `r"\".+\.m4a\""`

Combining it all together:

```py
import requests
import re

response = requests.get("https://soundgasm.net/u/rocketear/One-Art-by-Elizabeth-Bishop")
content = response.content.decode("utf-8")

file = re.search(re.compile(r"\".+\.m4a\""), content)
print(content[file.start():file.end()])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i learned a thing about xpath already, seems like a great function. If i use Firefox web developer to find/copy the relevant xpath it however seems to just refer to the line number the file link is on in the source being //*[@id="line71"]

Comment: The way I usually find elements on a webpage is by using an extension named ruto. I think this drastically speeds up my workflow since I don't have to scan the whole html.

Comment: Oh now I see your problem, let me get a working script for you.